# Custom QScrollArea widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qscrollarea

I am trying to create a class derived from QScrollArea, so I can promote ScrollArea to my custom class in form editor.
I have this code:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "CustomScrollArea.h"

CustomScrollArea::CustomScrollArea(QWidget *parent) :
QScrollArea (parent)
{
    setWidgetResizable( true );

    QWidget *widget = new QWidget();

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    widget->setLayout( layout );

    setWidget( widget );

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton( QString( "%1" ).arg( i ) );
        layout->addWidget( button );
    }
}
```

the problem I have is that buttons are not displayed that way...

the .ui contents:

```
...
<widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="CustomScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>221</width>
      <height>201</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="widgetResizable">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>0</y>
       <width>219</width>
       <height>199</height>
...
```

Comment: _ buttons are not displayed that way_ I am not able to find an evidence for that. Your code produces: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4BeJ.png

Comment: @scopchanov I have reproduced the problem, it only happens if the layout is created inside the constructor, if you do it after that, the problem is not generated.

Comment: maybe it only doesn't work on mac... I don't know... I get an empty scroll area,

Comment: @АлександрЛитвицкий It seems to me that it is a bug, in linux I also have that problem.

Comment: @АлександрЛитвицкий show your .ui

Comment: @eyllanesc  thank you very much.

Comment: @АлександрЛитвицкий Open it with any editor, the .ui is an xml, and then copy the content in your question

Comment: @eyllanesc, I have copied the exact same code. In `MainWindow` I have `setCentralWidget(new CustomScrollArea(this));` and nothing else.

Comment: It says that I can't because that way my post contains mostly code :/

Comment: @scopchanov The problem is when they promote it, read my answer.

Comment: @eyllanesc, now I see what you mean.

Comment: @АлександрЛитвицкий upload your .ui to drive, dropbox, github, etc and share the link.

Comment: @АлександрЛитвицкий I just need the .ui or else it follows what I indicated in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not caused by the code you shows but by Qt Designer, Qt Designer sets a default `scrollAreaWidgetContents` that is set in the QScrollArea replacing the previous widget.

[image]

```
 ...
 <widget class="CustomScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
  <property name="widgetResizable">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>380</width>
     <height>215</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 ...
```

So the solution is to manually remove those lines, open the .ui with an editor that supports XML and do that editing obtaining the following:

```
 ...
 <widget class="CustomScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
  <property name="widgetResizable">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
 </widget>
 ...
```

Then save the changes and compile.

Comment: I was a big fan of the form editor, but because of such things I have stopped using it. Anyway, you gave a nice solution.